# Django Haystack return related insances

Tags: django-haystack

Hi I´m using django with haystack search. I have one model for Events. Thats the model I'm doing the search on. I have a second model to count the hits/views for the Events. I wan't to return the number of hits for every event additional to the search results.

my view:

```
def event_search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = str(request.POST['search'])
        events = SearchQuerySet().auto_query(query).models(Event).order_by('date')
        return render_to_response('event_search.html', {"events": events}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('event_search.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 70)
   date = models.DateTimeField()
   description = models.TextField()
   active = models.BooleanField(default=True, editable=False)
   featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class EventHitcount(models.Model):
   hit = models.ForeignKey(Event)
   ip = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   session = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By giving the ForeignKey field a related name it can call and count the related objects.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey(Event,related_name='foofk')
    some more fields...
```

In the template:

```
{{ foo.foofk.count }}
```

Comment: how do i do something like this in the backend?